# How to change column type from oid to bytea in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

At first place, I got this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column xxxx is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 318
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
...
```

After googled a while, I think I should change the column type from oid to bytea. I tried this in the UI pgAdmin:

```
ALTER TABLE theTableName
ALTER COLUMN xxxx TYPE bytea
```

But I got error:

```
ERROR:  column "xxxx" cannot be cast automatically to type bytea
HINT:  You might need to specify "USING xxxx::bytea".
SQL state: 42804
```

Then I tried:

```
ALTER TABLE theTableName
ALTER COLUMN xxxx TYPE bytea USING xxxx::bytea
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type oid to bytea
LINE 2: ALTER COLUMN xxxx TYPE bytea USING xxxx::bytea
                                                ^
SQL state: 42846
Character: 88
```

- System: Windows 10
- PostgreSQL version :10
- pgAdmin 4 version: 3.0
- Python version 2.7.11
- Flask version: 0.12.2

May I ask how to solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like you have to use [the large object API](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/binary-data.html#binary-data-example) of the JDBC driver.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cast to `TEXT` then to `BYTEA`:

```
ALTER TABLE theTableName
ALTER COLUMN xxxx TYPE bytea USING xxxx::TEXT::BYTEA
```

**WARNING**

Note that this does not magically migrate any data! Hence, the large object sitting in `pg_largobject` referenced by the value stored in the oid column is not copied to the `theTableName` table. Only run this on empty tables or if you can afford to lose the large objects.

Comment: Thank you! You are right that it should be change to TEXT then to BYTEA. However, your code does not work for me. So I alter the column to TEXT first, then to bytea by ALTER COLUMN xxxx TYPE BYTEA USING xxxx::BYTEA